# Как закрыть изображение всех методов в классе Itelji Idea

Tags: java, intellij-idea

[image: Мои классы]
Как убрать показ всех этих методов, что б был просто класс без всех доп методов?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нужно убрать галку **Project** > **Show Options Menu** (кнопка шестеренки в верхнем правом углу) > **Tree Appearance** > **Show Members** [image: введите сюда описание изображения]